# Vim, when exiting without editing, creates unsaved buffer

Tags: text, vim

I am having some weird behavior when it comes to VIM.

The behavior that I'm expecting:
When editing a file, if one is in insert mode and doesn't make any file modifications when you exit insert mode the buffer should be considered "saved".

The behavior that I'm actually getting:
When editing a file and when I exit insert mode while making NO MODIFICATIONS, the buffer says that the file has been edited. Even though

I tested if this behavior was normal in vim by opening a clean version of vim, and it seems that the behavior I'm expecting is the default.

This a snippet of my config, my full configuration is here: (https://github.com/TheBabu/Config/blob/master/.vimrc)
I'm assuming whatever is causing this behavior is here otherwise it might be a plugin

```
"Setup
set shell=bash
set nowrap
set number
set nocompatible
set noshowmode
set directory^=$HOME/.vim/.swapfiles
set undofile
set mouse=a
syntax on
colorscheme neodark
hi Normal ctermbg=none
sign define transparent_sign
augroup SignColFixAu
    au!
    au BufReadPost *.c,*.cc,*.h,*.cpp,*.hh,*.hpp,*.py,*.js,*.php,*.rs exe "sign place 1111 name=transparent_sign line=1 file=".@%
augroup end
inoremap <cr> <space><bs><cr>
inoremap <esc> ~<bs><esc>
inoremap <expr> <up> pumvisible() ? "\<c-p>" : "~\<bs>\<up>"
inoremap <expr> <down> pumvisible() ? "\<c-p>" : "~\<bs>\<down>"
inoremap <Esc>x <Esc>x

"Tabs
set listchars=tab:➡\ 
set list
set autoindent
set noexpandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

..SNIP...

"Plugins
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plugin 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'
Plugin 'w0rp/ale'
Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plugin 'LukeLike/auto-pairs'
Plugin 'ananagame/vimsence'
Plugin 'preservim/nerdcommenter'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on

...SNIP...
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Those `inoremap`s you have for `Esc` and `CR` are very suspicious. Both are definitely modifying the buffer, by adding a character, then erasing it with backspace. Why do you even have those??? Not to mention that remapping `Esc` is a bad idea in general...

Comment: You were right! The issue at hand was `inoremap <esc> ~<bs><esc>` But the thing is that it breaks one of the functionalities that I have, where when I created a {}, when I hit enter it will automatically format it in the way that I want. Here is a demo of what I mean: https://asciinema.org/a/381897

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by your `<Esc>` mapping:

```
inoremap <esc> ~<bs><esc>
```

This mapping is inserting a `~` character then backspacing over it, which in practice doesn't change the contents, but still marks the buffer as modified. (Vim doesn't really track the exact contents of the buffer, but tracks whether any change was introduced, and both inserting `~` and backspacing over a character count as such.)

You mentioned in the comments you use this mapping (together with the `<CR>` mapping) to change how Vim behaves with indentation. The usual behavior of Vim is to remove auto-indentation when you move to a new line (with `<CR>` on an otherwise blank line) or leave Insert mode (with `<Esc>`.)

There doesn't seem to be a way to change this behavior in Vim. But the default Vim behavior is actually very useful, as it prevents ending up with lines with trailing spaces all over the place. (Many use Vim autocmd's to trim trailing whitespace on save and others use git hooks or code review bots to block source code files that have trailing whitespace.)

I imagine your motivation to keep the trailing whitespace is so that you can leave Insert mode and then later enter Insert mode again on that same line, while preserving indentation. But it turns out you don't really *need* to do that, since Vim has many ways to start Insert mode again with the proper indentation.

For example, if you insert a line above (with `O`) or below the current one (with `o`), Vim will insert the appropriate indentation on the new line. If you're on a blank line and want to start inserting there, then instead of using `i` to start Insert mode, use `S` to replace the contents of the current line. Since the line is empty, there won't be anything to replace, but the `S` command will start the replacement with the current indentation, so that should solve that too.

If you're already in Insert mode (and not necessarily at the beginning of a line), you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to have Vim apply the proper indentation to the current line, so that's an option too. With some languages (notably Python), Vim can't always figure out the proper indentation (since you indent to end a block), so Vim might not be able to guess right. In those cases, you also have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to increase indentation and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to decrease it. Both are Insert mode commands and can be executed anywhere in the line.

Hopefully with the use of these commands you'll be able to let go of the trailing spaces that you're using to track indentation and also drop those mappings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still think I want to be able to continue this behavior because even though those commands are helpful, its just nice to have the indention exit so my source code just looks generally easier to look at. I might just ask this behavior implemented into vim directly

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point to debug this might be comparing both original and modified versions after vim says its been edited.

To see the changes, use `git diff` if the file is VCS controlled, or `vim -d original_copy edited_copy` if it's not.

The diff-ed characters should give you an idea of the side-effect of the code that might be causing this. Paste the diff here if you can't figure that out.